# Excel Time to SQL Time

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime, vba

I am having some trouble inserting time into SQLServer
The data type in SQLServer is `time(0)`. I have the time in excel as `10:29:42`. (It is in 24-hour format)When I insert it into SQL the actual value being inserted is `0.4372917`
I get an error and the insert fails.Is there any way in VBA to have the actual value as `10:29:42'? This is my current code I use to copy from one sheet to another:

```
Test Time
Dim tt As String
tt = raw.Range("A7")
master.Range("F2") = tt
```

My insert Code is such:

```
Insert into Date_t( Date) Values(ActiveSheet.Range("F2"))
```

Comment: where is the code that does the insert ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.4372917 - part of day that have passed, multiply it with total seconds count in day to receive how many seconds passed since midnight

you should add seconds quantity to zero time:

```
Insert into Date_t( Date) Values(DATEADD(SECOND, ActiveSheet.Range("F2") * 24 * 60 * 60, CAST('00:00' AS TIME)))
```

P.S. it's better to use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores all dates internally as numbers.  What you're getting is that numeric representation.

If you want to use it in something like SQL, you will need to format it as a string.

```
Format(raw.Range("A7"), "HH:MM:SS")
```

will give you a result of "10:29:42"

use this in your SQL statement.

```
Insert into Date_t( Date) Values(Format(raw.Range("A7"), "HH:MM:SS"))
```

Some formatting of the string for single ticks around the date are probably necessary.  I'm not sure what kind of connection you're using though, so I can't give you that advise.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS this works fine:

```
select cast('10:21:50' as time)
```

Comment: The insert fails from excel VBA. I need help from VBA code

Comment: so you can use the string value from your cell as input to create the cast as shown here and use that in your insert statement to sql server

Comment: @GuidoG If i do that, it becomes CAST(0.4372917 as Time) because I would be doing CAST(ActiveSheet.Range("F2") as Time)

Comment: @SQLserving you use like `ws.Range("A3").Text` which will give you what you see on screen and iwll return literally `10:21:50`